# Master Detail with Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a master detail view with some nested JSON and am out of ideas. I know I am probably missing something simple here but I turn to you all for help.

This is a sample of the JSON. There are around 50 Items with the same number and letter pattern (e.g. 1a, 30d, etc).

```
{
   "Items": [
   {
      "Name": "Item 1",
      "Number: 1
      "Subcategories": [
       {
          "Name": Sub Item 1",
          "Letter: "A",
          "Description": "A description about the item..."
       }
          "Name": Sub Item 2",
          "Letter: "B",
          "Description": "A description about the item..."  
       }    
       }
          "Name": Sub Item 3"
          "Letter: "C",
          "Description": "A description about the item..."  
       }    
   }
}
```

I have successfully set up the master page with an accordion that lists all the items in the list that when clicked, displays all of the sub items but where I am getting confused is when I click on the sub menu item and am routed to the details page, I can only view the name parameter that is stored in $state.params. I want the details page to be able to display the description as well.

Here is the accordion list:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
              <ion-item class="item-stable"
                        ng-click="toggleGroup(item)"
                        ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(item)}">
                  <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(item) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>

                {{item.name}}
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                        ng-repeat="item_type in item.subcategories"
                        ng-show="isGroupShown(item)"
                        ng-click="onSelectItems(item_type)">
                  {{item_type.name}}
              </ion-item>
            </div>
```

Here is the relevant app.js .config:

```
  .state('tab.item-listing', {
    url:'/item-listing',
    views: {
      'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/item-listing.html',
        controller: 'itemListingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.itemDetail', {
  url:'/:name',

  views: {
    'tab-home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/item-detail.html',
      controller: 'itemListingDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the relevant function within the itemListingsCtrl controller:

```
$scope.onSelectItems = function(item_type) {

        var params = {
            name: item_type.name,
        };

        $state.go('tab.itemDetail', params);

        console.log($state.params);

};

});
```

Here is the controller for itemListingDetailCtrl:

```
.controller("itemListingDetailCtrl", function ($scope, itemService, $stateParams, $state)
{
  console.log($state.params);

  $scope.name = $state.params.name;


})
```

Finally, this is the relevant section from the service.js that pulls in the JSON.

```
.factory('itemService', function($http,$location) {

  var items = [];

  return {

    getitems: function(){
      return $http.get(/path/to/JSON).then(function(resp){

        items = resp.data.items;

        return items;

      });
    },

  }
});
```

Is anyone able to lend a hand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass the whole object as `params`

Comment: Is there an accepted method to do this?

Comment: no different than passing the object you are creating. Delete that object and then `$state.go('tab.itemDetail', item_type)`

Comment: So that wouldn't save the entire JSON as an object in state? Just the details under item_type?

Comment: an object is nothing but a reference. Not really sure what you are asking

Comment: So if I do that, in my detail page I should be able to reference {{name}}, {{letter}} and {{description}} directly? Is that how it works?

Sorry, am at work at the moment so will try when I'm home.

Comment: If you want to get that info as you say, you should start using ```_.lodash```, I did not get your question, just a little part of it. But ```_.lodash``` could help you a lot.